# If $\omega$ is an n-form that is left-invariant, show $f \cdot \omega$ left-invariant for $f$ a smooth function.

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $G$ is a Lie group. Let $\omega$ be a left-invariant $n$-form on $G$. Let $f$ be a smooth function, why would $f \cdot \omega$ be left-invariant?

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily be. For example, let $x \in G$ be such that $\omega(x) \ne 0$. By left-invariance, $\omega(gx) \ne 0$. But there are smooth functions $f$ such that $f(x) = 0$ and $f(gx) = 1$. Then $f \omega$ can't be left invariant.

Comment: @JakeLevinson What if $\omega$ is an n-form volume form and G is of dimension n?

Comment: The same counterexample applies.